# AddColumns says I'm comparing a number to a table

Tags: sql, powerapps

I'm somewhat new to PowerApps and I'm stuck at trying to reproduce a JOIN using the `AddColumns` function and a `LookUp` function as I saw on this link: [Syntax for joining tables](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Syntax-for-joining-tables/td-p/61387). This JOIN will go inside of a Data Table.

I have two SQL tables I'm trying to JOIN using that method

**mT_SalesAttributeDB_FamilyMaterialGroupMaterials:** ([ID], [MaterialGroupID], [MaterialID], [Comment], [Created], [Updated])

**mT_SalesAttributeDB_Materials:** ([ID], [MaterialName], [Description], [ShortDesc], [Abbr], [Superseded], [HasNoDrawing], [Created], [Updated])

What I'm wanting to accomplish is this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    mT_SalesAttributeDB_FamilyMaterialGroupMaterials AS Grps
    INNER JOIN
    mT_SalesAttributeDB_Materials AS Mats ON Grps.MaterialID = Mats.ID
WHERE
    Grps.MaterialGroupID = tblMaterialGroups_Families.Selected.ID
```

I think this is what that should look like:

```
AddColumns(
    Filter(
        mT_SalesAttributeDB_FamilyMaterialGroupMaterials, 
        Text(tblMaterialGroups_Families.Selected.ID) = MaterialGroupID
    ), 
    "MaterialName", 
    LookUp(
        mT_SalesAttributeDB_Materials, 
        ID = mT_SalesAttributeDB_FamilyMaterialGroupMaterials[@MaterialID], 
        MaterialName
    )
)
```

However, the equality inside of the LookUp, `ID = mT_SalesAttributeDB_FamilyMaterialGroupMaterials[@MaterialID]` gives an error on the equal sign saying I can't compare a number to a table

As a reference, I've tried this and it works fine

```
Filter(
    mT_SalesAttributeDB_FamilyMaterialGroupMaterials, 
    Text(tblMaterialGroups_Families.Selected.ID) = MaterialGroupID
)
```

Is the problem that I'm trying to use a preview object that isn't fully released? Or am I joining them incorrectly?

**EDIT**

I've also tried this and still get the same error about not being able to compare a number to a Table

```
AddColumns(
    Filter(
        mT_SalesAttributeDB_FamilyMaterialGroupMaterials, 
        mT_SalesAttributeDB_FamilyMaterialGroupMaterials[@MaterialGroupID] = Text(tblMaterialGroups_Families.Selected.ID)
    ), 
    "SpecName", 
    LookUp(
        mT_SalesAttributeDB_Materials, 
        mT_SalesAttributeDB_Materials[@ID] = mT_SalesAttributeDB_FamilyMaterialGroupMaterials[@MaterialID],
        mT_SalesAttributeDB_Materials[@MaterialName]
    )
)
```

**NOTE:** I also wanted to mention that I attempted the exact same AddColumns with a List Box to make sure it wasn't something to do with Data Tables being in preview, and I still get the error that I can't compare a Number to a Table

**EDIT 2**

I seem to be getting close. I can get the error to stop and it to populate "SpecName", however, it just grabs the first MaterialName from mT_SalesAttributeDB_Materials instead of doing a proper LookUp

```
AddColumns(
    Filter(
        mT_SalesAttributeDB_FamilyMaterialGroupMaterials, 
        MaterialGroupID = Text(tblMaterialGroups_Families.Selected.ID)
    ), 
    "MaterialName", 
    LookUp(
        mT_SalesAttributeDB_Materials, 
        ID in mT_SalesAttributeDB_FamilyMaterialGroupMaterials.MaterialID,
        MaterialName
    )
)
```

I changed the "=" to an "in" and it seems that `mT_SalesAttributeDB_FamilyMaterialGroupMaterials.MaterialID` is the same as `mT_SalesAttributeDB_FamilyMaterialGroupMaterials[@MaterialID]`

Comment: I will just add this here so you can try out. I have no knowledge of powerapps but looking at your "should look like"  section it seems odd that some places you use fully qualified field path and in the look up you use table array with the field as parameter of the array.. so maybe instead of `ID = mT_SalesAttributeDB_FamilyMaterialGroupMaterials[@MaterialID]` try `ID = mT_SalesAttributeDB_FamilyMaterialGroupMaterials.MaterialID` ?
Again, this is purely a suggestion out of my OCD triggering out of different patterns :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did try that too

Comment: There's a mismatch in the SQL between the alias definition (`Grps`) and how it's used (`Grp`). Hopefully that's just a typo in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I finally got it with some help from Google. I had a few things that were likely causing me problems with my tables.

1. _Materials.MaterialID was changed to .MaterialName so I wouldn't have two fields with the same name but different meanings. I think that helped when PowerApps was using context.
2. _Materials.ID is stored as an INT however, for some reason I decided to store _FamilyMaterialGroupMaterials as a VARCHAR. So I changed that to an INT so MaterialID and ID would be exactly the same thing in each table. (I assume this helps with the JOIN)

Once I had that updated, this is the correct syntax to JOIN two tables. You can see I even added in a second Column once I got it working

```
AddColumns(
    Filter(
        mT_SalesAttributeDB_FamilyMaterialGroupMaterials, 
        MaterialGroupID = tblMaterialGroups_Families.Selected.ID
    ),
    "MaterialName",
    LookUp(
        mT_SalesAttributeDB_Materials,
        ID = MaterialID
    ).MaterialName,
    "ShortDesc",
    LookUp(
        mT_SalesAttributeDB_Materials,
        ID = MaterialID
    ).ShortDesc
)
```

Hopefully my full day wasted trying to figure that out will help someone else.